# How can I prove that this matrices statement is false?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

How can I prove that this is not true:

If for matrices A, B and C, AB=AC and A is not the zeroth matrix, then B=C.

Comment: Find an example of matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A$ is not the all-zero matrix, $AB=AC$, but $B \neq C$.

Comment: The zeroth matrix?  Are we counting them now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $AB=AC$ then $A(B-C)=0$, and we can use the fact that the product of two non-zero matrices can be zero, so that both $A$ is non-zero and $B-C$ is non-zero, so that $B\neq C$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can find a counterexample with $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find a counter-example, like
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix},\quad
C=\begin{bmatrix}
2\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yeah right... Thanks for edit.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$ than $AB=AC \Rightarrow B=C$. But isf $A$ is not invertible $B$ and $C$ can be different.

As noteed in other answers you can have as example a matrix :

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and you see that for 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\b&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
You have $AB=0$, so for different values of $b$ you have different matrices that multiplied by $A$ give the same result, i.e. the null matrix.

But, note that this is true also for matrices of the form:

$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}b&0\\c&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

for which you have:

$$
AC=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b&0\\c&0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ab&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
so, for different values of $c$, you have the same product that is not the null matrix.